# Creating one shape inside another

Tags: svg

We can create shapes like rectangle, circle etc. Can we create a rectangle inside another rectangle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't create a rectangle inside an other rectangle. But you can make 2 rectangles to look so.

You use the <rect> tag for rectangles. By looking at the rectangle description in the [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement), you can see that the content model don't allow <rect> to contain an other <rect> (or shape).

An example of what you can do :

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100"/>
<rect x="25" y="25" width="150" height="50"/>
```

You can also add a <g> around those two rectangles to group them, like this :

```
<g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100"/>
    <rect x="25" y="25" width="150" height="50"/>
</g>
```

More explanations here : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups

You also have the alternative of using a path to draw 2 rectangles with only one tag. It all depend of your needs.

Comment: @PradeepNeo <g>